# is RADIO-SIGNAL Jammer safe for health?

Tags: radioactivity, radiology

Recently, I had to overview some WiFi technologies, and then wanted to check [**RADIOSIGNAL-BLOCKER**](http://www.jammerfromchina.com/products/14_Antennas_Adjustable_3G_4G_Cellphone_Signal_Blocker_%26_WiFi_GPS_UHF_VHF_%26_Full_Bands_Signal_Jammer.html) hardware (a.k.a. WiFi/Cellural-Signal/Bluetooth/ Jammer).

We needed to use that technology to block mobile-phones in our hall, to avoid noise during some important events..  But I was interested, if it is harmful for peoples health (for example, averagely 3 hours a day it will be turned ON in our office).

thanks in advance

Comment: here was a big discussion - http://superuser.com/questions/945022/wireless-if-harmful-is-a-bigger-wifi-antenna-a-bigger-health-hazard

Comment: Aside from health concerns you have one big problem: Operating such a jammer is illegal in the US and most other developed nations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're in the U.S. and the jammer is mounted atop your building, you need to do an [environmental assessment if your transmit power is over 1000 watts](https://transition.fcc.gov/bureaus/oet/info/documents/bulletins/oet65/oet65.pdf). However, as Carey Gregory mentioned, if you're jamming signals in the U.S., you have other legal problems (and you *will* be jamming signals at 1000 watts). If you're planning on mounting the jammer in the building itself, I don't think you can use the rooftop limits--you would likely need to use the other equations in the document I linked.

I'm only addressing RF-burn risk here. Whether RF radiation has any effect on cancer incidence is an ongoing much-disputed research topic.